# Gmail password on another device.

Tags: privacy

I sold my android phone. I had account saved for google apps. When I change my password of gmail account,  can it be possible to log in from previous phone by buyer?

Answer (score 2):

Changing your password ***should*** be all you need to do.

In addition to this (if it were me), I'd turn on two-factor authentication.  This will require a code (sent through SMS or from an authenticator app on your new phone) to be typed in, in addition to your password and will ensure only you are able to log on to your account.

That being said, you can also take extra precautions and go to the Google Account Security page and make sure that only the devices and computers and apps that you want to have access to your account actually do:  https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security

Another link for reference detailing the de-authorization of other app passwords and devices that are potentially using your account:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/tHVFkE1nsZ4

Comment: Thanks.  I changed my password.  That means my account is safe from previous device and user right?

Comment: Like I said, this should take care of any place where you previously used your account and effectively render it useless on your old phone, but I'd still run through the steps I mentioned above.

Comment: @Navarajadhikari You can show your thanks with an up-vote and marking his answer as such. =)